# ggplotly text aesthetic causing geom_line to not display

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to render a simple geom_line with a tooltip defined by a text aesthetic.

```
q <- ggplot(data = graphDataFactor(), aes(x = Dates,
                                          y=Variable_Data, 
                                          colour = Variable_Name
                                          #,
                                        #text = paste('Date: ', as.Date(Dates),
                                        #'<br>Variable:', Variable_Name,
                                        #'<br>Var Unit:', Variable_Data
                                                  #)
                                                  )) + 
          geom_line(size = 1) + 
          labs(colour = "Variables") 
ggplotly(q
         #, tooltip = c("text")
         )
```

So this code with the text aesthetic commented out works fine and renders the line. However, when I try to use the text aesthetic and tooltip, the geom_line does not appear in the plot. Hovering over the correct locations does show the right tooltip, and the colour legend displays properly.

Also, I have an identical call where the only difference is that I call geom_point rather than geom_line and that renders perfectly fine.

Is this just a bug with ggplotly or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add `group=1` when setting aesthetics.

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(Dates = c("01/14/92", "02/27/92", "03/27/92", "04/28/92", "01/03/92"),
                 Variable_Data=runif(5), Variable_Name=c("A","A","A","B","B"))
df$Dates <- as.Date(df$Dates,"%m/%d/%y")

q <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Dates, y=Variable_Data, 
                           colour=Variable_Name, group=1,
     text = paste('Date: ', Dates,
                  '<br>Variable:', Variable_Name, 
                  '<br>Var Unit:', Variable_Data))) + 
     geom_line(size = 1) + labs(colour = "Variables") 

ggplotly(q, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this fixed the error. Is this just a bug with the text aesthetic or is there a reason it works like this?

Comment: @StefanLangenborg In my opinion it is not a bug, but I have not yet a clear explanation of why it is necessary to  use `group=1`

Comment: Awesome! That would have driven me nuts