# Tooltip for lines with ggplot and ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

The following code draws a triangle in `ggplotly`. I want to use the labels (from my data frame) as tooltips. How can I do this?

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggplotly)

data_points <- tibble(Node = c(1,2,3), X = c(1,2,1.5), Y = c(4,5,6))
data_segments <- tibble(From = c(1,2,3), To = c(2,3,1), label = c('Line 1: 800', 'Line 2: 1600', 'Line 3: 400'))
data <- data_segments %>% 
  left_join(data_points %>% rename(From = Node, X_from = X, Y_from = Y)) %>% 
  left_join(data_points %>% rename(To = Node, X_to = X, Y_to = Y))

p <- ggplot(data) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = X_from, y = Y_from)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = X_from, y = Y_from, xend = X_to, yend = Y_to, text = label))
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Instead of getting this tooltip by hovering over a point, I want to have it on a line.

I've found a few related items on points like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325154/how-to-choose-variable-to-display-in-tooltip-when-using-ggplotly), but none of them seem to work with lines.

Basically they all use the aesthetic text or label to render the effect. The problem is that `geom_segment` and `geom_line` don't accept this aesthetic. Is there another way around this issue?

There are others that mention issues with lines, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948926/ggplotly-text-aesthetic-causing-geom-line-to-not-display), but that is also not the problem I'm looking for.

Edit: it seems that there are some options with traces which is the plotly equivalent of a line. However, so far I've only found working results with traces where the lines have a lot of corners or bends (e.g. the density plot [here](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/extending-ggplotly.html)). With straight lines, the tooltips still end up on the points.

Comment: Cannot give tooltip between end points as there is no data points defined for any point in between the corners.  You can check that in a `plotly_build(p)` object.  In stat_smooth or geom_smooth data points are defined.