# How to use crosstalk with bar + line plot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, crosstalk

I am new to **crosstalk** & trying to make **rmarkdown** file more interactive by using on **bar+line** plot but it is **not giving line** on the plot and also **gets weird when I change country**.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)
library(glue)
library(scales)
library(tidytext)
```

load data:

```
file_url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johnsnow09/covid19-df_stack-code/main/test_crosswalk.csv"

test_df <- read.csv(url(file_url))
```

```
Country_selected = c("Brazil") 
selected_case_type = c("Confirmed_daily")

trend_sd <- test_df %>% 
                filter(Daily_Cases_type %in% selected_case_type
                       # Country.Region %in% Country_selected, 
                       ) %>%   
              select(Country.Region, date, Cases_count)%>%
              arrange(date) %>% 
              group_by(Country.Region) %>% 
              mutate(new_avg = cumsum(Cases_count)/ seq_len(length(Cases_count))) %>% 
              ungroup() %>% 
              SharedData$new()


bscols(widths = c(9, 3),
       list(
  filter_select(id = "country", label = "Country:", sharedData =  trend_sd, group =  ~ Country.Region),
  
  
  ggplotly(ggplot(data = trend_sd) +
            geom_col(aes(x = date, y = Cases_count), fill = "turquoise", alpha = .3) +
            geom_point(aes(x = date, y = new_avg), col = "tomato") +
            geom_line(aes(x = date, y = new_avg), col = "tomato", size = .9, alpha = .3) +
            scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
            # expand_limits(y = 100000) +
            
            labs(title = glue("{Country_selected}'s {selected_case_type} Cases {date_from} onwards"),
                 caption = "Data source: covid19.analytics") 
  ))
)
```

This doesn't give correct line plot & even when I change country to some other then bars gets distorted.

[image]

---

### **Code & Plot Result** below **without crosstalk & plotly**:

```
Country_selected = c("India")  # can be selective
selected_case_type = c("Confirmed_daily")

  test_df %>% 
                filter(Daily_Cases_type %in% selected_case_type,
                       Country.Region %in% Country_selected,
                       ) %>%   
              select(Country.Region, date, Cases_count)%>%
              arrange(date) %>% 
              group_by(Country.Region) %>% 
              mutate(new_avg = cumsum(Cases_count)/ seq_len(length(Cases_count))) %>% 
              ungroup() %>%   
  
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = date, y = Cases_count), fill = "turquoise", alpha = .3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = date, y = new_avg), col = "tomato") +
  geom_line(aes(x = date, y = new_avg), col = "tomato", size = .9, alpha = .3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) +
  
  labs(title = glue("{Country_selected}'s {selected_case_type} Cases {date_from} onwards"),
       subtitle = "With Average Daily Cases Trend line",
       caption = "Data source: covid19.analytics")
```

[image]

Comment: One issue is that there should be a closing parenthesis on the first list inside the `bscols` call, before ggplotly

Comment: I have the same problem (disappearing line). Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mzuba I haven't tried to solve this again.

Comment: I realize that this is an old post, but I am also having the same issue.  Wondering if there were any new thoughts on it?

Comment: @ViSa, @mzuba I believe that you need to use `group=date` in your aes.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45948926/ggplotly-text-aesthetic-causing-geom-line-to-not-display.  I was able to get it to work for me by adding this.